# Get summary vectors of raster cell centers in R

Tags: r, raster

I want to extract summary vectors that contain the coordinates for the centers of the different cells in a raster.  The following code works but I believe involves an n-squared comparison operation.  Is there a more efficient method?  Not seeing anything obvious in {raster}'s guidance.

```
require(raster)
r = raster(volcano)
pts = rasterToPoints(r)
x_centroids = unique(pts[,1])
y_centroids = unique(pts[,2])
```

Comment: I'm not entirely following. What you have now, is the unique x and y coordinates of the points. How that translates to centroids, is unclear to me.

Comment: Perhaps centroids isn't the best word, but you have at least correctly interpreted the desired output.

Comment: What's the use case? The supplied example obviously runs very fast. How large is your dataset? `unique` seems to be very quick up to ~10^5 elements, then slows down.

Comment: @geotheory I've adapted your question to reflect the true problem

Comment: @nico yes `unique` is fine for normal use, but my code is looping so any gain is good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the centers of the raster cells, you should use the functions `xFromCol`, `yFromRow` and friends (see also the help pages)

In this case, you get exactly the same result as follows:

```
require(raster)
r <- raster(volcano)
x_centers <- xFromCol(r)
y_centers <- yFromRow(r)
```

Note that these functions actually don't do much else but check the minimum value of the coordinates and the resolution of the raster. From these two values, they calculate the sequence of centers as follows:

```
xmin(r) + (seq_len(ncol(r)) - 0.5) * xres(r)

ymin(r) + (seq_len(nrow(r)) - 0.5) * xres(r)
```

But you better use the functions mentioned above, as these do a bit more safety checks.